# firemonkey how to forward mouse event to parent?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I know the property Hitest, but this property is all or nothing :( what i want is to keep the control able to receive the onclick event but at the same time forward to the parent all the movedown, mousemove, mouseup event.

why? because i discover that the scrollbox use the CMGesture to catch mouse event trapped on child control. The problem is that CMGESTURE is less accurate than mousemove and more slow :( so i would like to find an easy way to forward to the parent all mouse event of his child